# How can I make a Phaser game automatically fill the window?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

How can I make a Phaser game automatically fill the browser window? (And ideally, automatically refill if the window changes size.) I know that there is a [ScaleManager class](http://docs.phaser.io/Phaser.ScaleManager.html) but the docs aren't clear how to use it. I've also found [other instructions](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/5949-solution-scaling-for-multiple-devicesresolution-and-screens/) but they don't indicate where to add the code they suggest, and running it immediately after creating the Game class doesn't seem to do anything.

I am currently using the base code found [in this tutorial](http://www.photonstorm.com/phaser/tutorial-making-your-first-phaser-game), but am willing to change that completely.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out to be quite simple, you just need to run this code in a preload or create function (instead of immediately after creating a game instance, as I had been trying).

```
this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
//this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
this.scale.setScreenSize( true );
```

Note that setting this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally to true will actually mess up the horizontal alignment if you make the game go fullscreen. Instead you can centre the canvas with css:

```
canvas { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: **this.scale.setScreenSize( true );** is not working in Phaser new version. Then what should use ?

Comment: @ShohanurRahaman I don't know sorry, you should ask a new question for the new version.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the setShowAll Method of the ScaleManager
By default this function has an if which switches on "expanding",
expanding is a parameter which gets set to true if you go into fullscreen  mode.
But since we always want to "expand" i just removed the if.

```
module.exports = function () {

  Phaser.ScaleManager.prototype.setShowAll = function () {
    let bounds = this.getParentBounds(this._tempBounds);
    let width = bounds.width;
    let height = bounds.height;
    let multiplier = Math.max((height / this.game.height), (width / this.game.width));

    this.width = Math.round(this.game.width * multiplier);
    this.height = Math.round(this.game.height * multiplier);
  };

  window.Game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
};
```

this kills the possibility to update, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Right now (Phaser 2.4.4) you do this simply by setting the scale mode, for example within your create function:

```
game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
```

game.scale.scaleMode controls how the game is scaled when NOT in full screen mode.

http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.ScaleManager.html#scaleMode